# .net C# jdbc driver connector exception

Tags: c#, .net, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm trying to connect to a hyperSQL database (HSQLDB) on my local machine from a c# application in visual studio.

I've ran through the steps to create the .net JDBC driver to build the dll, and also downloading the demo console application in the "download" section from the following url: http://nikolaiklimov.de/query-java-HyperSQL-database-with-csharp/

The demo application works!! i can connect to the database and query its contents . Next I have converted the console app into a class library then call the class library to query the DB but this is where it falls over and I get initialization errors of System.TypeInitializationException. any idea why the project falls over after converting to a class library. (if i convert the class library straight back a console app it works again).

The code and connection string are:

```
namespace HyperSQL
{
public static class sqlconnector
{
             readonly static string CONNECTION_STRING =   
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HyperSQL"].ConnectionString;
             const string SQL = "SELECT * FROM meeting";

    public static void getdata()
    {
        try
        {


        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver());
        using (java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
        {
            java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);
            using (java.sql.ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery())
            {
                while (rs.next())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"MEETING_NO={rs.getInt("MEETING_NO")}");

                    Console.WriteLine("------------------");
                }
            }
        }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}

jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:3458/elitedb;crypt_key=DADADADADAADDADAD;crypt_type=AES;shutdown=true;write_delay=false;user=****;password=****
```

Ive added a console app to my solution after the conversion to a class libary. The console app code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                HyperSQL.sqlconnector.getdata();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a link to download my solution created in visual studio. It contains a console application that calls a function in a class library. The class library (HyperSQL) itself is simply converted from a console application and can be converted back. You will need a running instance of HyperSQL on your machine to be able to connect successfully.
http://eliteservicedev.azurewebsites.net/DemoHyperSQL.zip

Comment: provide the code to initialize the type where this method exist..how are you calling the class?

Comment: amended to add calling code

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the error listed in the original site you posted?

> If your forget to add runtime dependencies to the build folder of your
>   project then you can get these errors:  Could not load file or
>   assembly 'IKVM.OpenJDK.Util, Version=8.1.5717.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.  TypeInitializationException:
>   The type initializer for 'org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver' threw an
>   exception: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'IKVM.Runtime, Version=8.1.5717.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58' or one of its dependencies.  'The
>   type initializer for 'sun.util.locale.provider.LocaleProviderAdapter'
>   threw an exception.' FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'IKVM.OpenJDK.Text, Version=8.1.5717.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=13235d27fcbfff58' or one of its dependencies.  'The
>   type initializer for 'org.hsqldb.HsqlDateTime' threw an exception.'
>   InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'java.util.PropertyResourceBundle' to type
>   'sun.util.resources.OpenListResourceBundle'.

***** UPDATE
With the source project i see an error, looking in the bin\debug folder i see that non all the referenced file are copied to ConsoleApp1.exe bin folder: this is the compare result:

```
Confronto in corso dei file consoleapp1.txt e DEMOCSHARPTHYPERSQL.TXT
***** consoleapp1.txt
ConsoleApp1.exe
ConsoleApp1.exe.config
ConsoleApp1.pdb
hsqldb.dll
HyperSQL.dll
***** DEMOCSHARPTHYPERSQL.TXT
hsqldb.dll
HyperSQL.dll
*****

***** consoleapp1.txt
IKVM.OpenJDK.Jdbc.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.Text.dll
***** DEMOCSHARPTHYPERSQL.TXT
IKVM.OpenJDK.Jdbc.dll
IKVM.OpenJDK.Localedata.dll --> Missing in ConsoleApp1.exe folder
IKVM.OpenJDK.Text.dll
*****
```

If i manually copy the missing dll on ConsoleApp1.exe folder the program run correctly. I think that is a visual studio bug

Comment: Hi, the runtime dependencies are added and available in the debug folder after I clean and build the whole solution. The fact that the project as a console app works as required should mean the dependencies don't need to be changed? or do i need to add dependencies to the calling project after converting to a class library? Well and truly stuck at the minute!

Comment: " the runtime dependencies are added and available in the debug folder", this is the debug folder of the calling project that at the moment give you an error? What means "then call the class library to query the DB", who is the caller exe of this library?

Comment: The caller exe (or project) of the library is consoleapp1. Its consoleapp1 that calls the "getdata" function exposed by the hypersql library. All dependencies exist only in the "hypersql" project, the calling exe does not have any dependencies required to connect to jdbc bridge.

Comment: The problem is related to a reference to a "IKVM.Runtime.dll", if you change the copy local attribute (his final value must be true) to this reference and recompile all the project seems work

Comment: Hi, after making that change i still get the same error :( "type initializer threw an exception". if you put a breakpoint on the "catch (Exception ex)" line in the consoleapp1 project the exception is visible. are you able to see this also?

Comment: I've modified the answer, i see your error and i see that in ConsoleApp1.exe folder thare is one dll missing

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have moved the file across manually as you did but unfortunately i'm getting the same exception at the same place. However now in my main application i have tried to import the class library in its current state and can see more debugging information. The exception is now from the IKVM.OpenJDK.Util file and the details are "The type initializer for 'sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile' threw an exception". The inner exception details are system.missingmethod exception

Answer (score 0):

Seems VS is not copying all IKVM DLLs to output folder due to not resolving they are needed. Please see this [SourceForge issue](https://sourceforge.net/p/ikvm/mailman/message/35051603/) and this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/KevM/tikaondotnet/issues/118), the later one with my comments.